# Unable to commit or push zipped files under 50 MB to GitHub using Windows Git Bash

Tags: git, bash, zip, push, commit

I'm trying to solve two dilemmas here.  The first is more critical and is the ultimate question here.  The second is on my wish list.

I added three new files to a new repository called `test`.  `test1.csv` (88,507 KB) and `test2.txt` (330,854 KB).  And one more file which is VERY SMALL in size.  I called `git add *`, then I called `git commit -m "comment"`, and then called `git push`.  That threw errors that said the file sizes were too large.  Now after removing the two large files, and leaving the third small file.  I did add, commit and push again.  And I get this output.  What's strange is that I get to file max sizes.  50 MB and 100 MB.

1. When I zip these files up individually, I can get the file size pretty small.  `test1.csv` zipped into `test1.zip` becomes 3,552 KB and `test2.txt` zipped into `test2.zip` becomes 16,200 KB.  Even after removing those two files and adding the two small compressed files, I get the output (below).  So it thinks the old files are still there, maybe?  How can I push these files, as well as the third very small file?
2. The output says the max file size is 50 MB as well as 100 MB.  What is correct?

   ```
   mac231@UH-WF-320-61 MINGW64 /c/git/test (master)
   $ git push
   warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value has changed in
   Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
   and maintain the traditional behavior, use:

     git config --global push.default matching

   To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

     git config --global push.default simple

   When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
   to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

   Since Git 2.0, Git defaults to the more conservative 'simple'
   behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
   remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.

   See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
   (the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
   'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

   Counting objects: 19, done.
   Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
   Compressing objects: 100% (15/15), done.
   Writing objects: 100% (19/19), 37.45 MiB | 1.54 MiB/s, done.
   Total 19 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
   remote: warning: File RAW/private/test1.csv is 86.33 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
   remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
   remote: error: Trace: df96709b4791777b7cb9d64d19a61dab
   remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
   remote: error: File RAW/private/test2.txt is 322.71 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
   To https://github.com/xxx/test.git
    ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
   error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xxx/test.git'

   mac231@UH-WF-320-61 MINGW64 /c/git/test (master)
   $
   ```

Here's the Git version, according to the Git Bash command prompt:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.7.0.windows.1
```

**EDIT #1:**

```
mac231@UH-WF-320-61 MINGW64 /c/git/test (master)
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 4 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: `The output says the max file size is 50 MB as well as 100 MB.` It doesn't. It says the __recommended__ maximum file size is 50 MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sad that I had to resort to this as a fix for the Git API, such a popular version control system.  Or it's the GitHub website that still has some major issues to be fixed yet.  Not the best solution in the world, but it worked.  And this was caused by such a simple workflow too!

- make a copy of the new files
- `cd {path of 'test' parent folder}`
- deleted root folder named 'test'
- `git clone https://github.com/{organization name}/test.git`
- move new files into folder test
- `cd {path of 'test'}`
- `git add *`
- `git commit -m "comment"`
- `git push`

Answer (score 0):

The **maximum** size is `100 MB`, the ***recommended*** size is `50 MB`.

The error message:

```
remote: warning: File RAW/private/test1.csv is 86.33 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: df96709b4791777b7cb9d64d19a61dab
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File RAW/private/test2.txt is 322.71 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

Seems to complain the main issue as being `File RAW/private/test2.txt is 322.71 MB`.

When you add the files try using the `-u` option, which records the names of the deleted files:

```
git add -u .
```

Check what's staged to be committed with:

```
git status
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work.  I'm concerned that this is either a Git issue or a GitHub website issue, for such a simple workflow.